# Get list of executions filtered by parameter value

Tags: spring-batch

I am using Spring-batch 3.0.4 stable. While submitting a job I add some specific parameters to its execution, say, a tag. Jobs information is persisted in the DB.

Later on I will need to retrieve all the executions marked with a particular tag.

Currently I see 2 options:

1. Get all job instances with `org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer#findJobInstancesByJobName`. For each instance get all available executions with `org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer#getJobExecutions`. Filter the resulting collection of executions checking its `JobParameters`.
2. Write my own JdbcTemplate-based DAO implementation to run the select query.

While the former option seems pretty inefficient, the latter one suggests writing extra code to deal with the Spring-specific database tables structure.

Is there any option I am missing here?

Comment: Nope.  You're on the right track.  To be honest, I'd recommend 2.

Comment: Option 2 assumes that you're using the JDBC implementation of the DAOs, which is not always the case. Spring Batch also comes with an in-memory implementation for those who don't need long-term persistence, and there are implementations for other databases (I've made my own for MongoDB https://github.com/ogerardin/springframework-batch-dao-mongodb).
Using option 1, although not optimal performance-wise, would work with any DAO implementation.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Is there a spring-batch function that you could use?